# How to extract List attribute from session in Gatling?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

In Gatling 2.1 I'm saving bunch of Ids like this:

```
.findAll.saveAs("ids"))
```

This adds list of Ids in session:

```
ids -> List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

I'd like to have this list as regular Scala variable.

In case of Strings it works fine:

```
.exec(session => {      
    val mystring= session("SomeString").as[String]
    session
  })
```

How do I make this work for a List?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just cast into a List instead of a String.

Assuming you really have a List[Int] as in your sample, and not a List[String]:

```
.exec { session =>  
  val mystring= session("SomeString").as[List[Int]]
  session
}
```